# PHP stripslashes problem

Tags: php, stripslashes

I have a development machine that is local and a server out on the net. Weird thing is that when I use stripslashes on my development machine, all slashes are removed and when I upload the same code to the net server, I see the escape character even though I am using stripslashes. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be [Magic Quotes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Try to [disable them or remove them](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) before processing the data.

Comment: I just checked the ini file on the server and magic_quotes is set to ON. Shouldn't this be disabled for security reasons? What is the norm?

Comment: @Jim: They should be disabled if possible. But applications need to be aware that they might be enabled/disabled and should be able to remove them.  Or at least they shouldn’t rely on that they are always enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what the note says on the [manual page](http://hu2.php.net/stripslashes) might be the problem.