# How to filter the follow JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json, payment-gateway

I am performing a query against a Payment Gateway and this is part of a JSON I am receiving as reply:

```
"//{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\",\"INV_ID_EXT\",\"CUST_ID_EXT\",\"MERCH_ID\", ... ,null,\"510510\",1,24]]}"
```

How can I delete from the string the "\" to get transform in a real JSON?

What I did so far:

```
echo $JSON2 = str_replace("//","",$theString);
```

I get this:

```
"{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\", ...
```

When I try `str_replace("\\","",$JSON2);` I still have the `"{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\", ...`

For some reason I am able to remove the `//` but not `\` .

How could I remove the `\`  from this string without loop character by character?

Comment: stripslashes could be the droid you're looking for - http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Hi, this is what I get $JSON = stripslashes ($theString);  Result= "//{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\",\"INV_ID_EXT\",\"CUST_ID_EXT\", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried like this using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes)? see here https://eval.in/836989

```
<?php
$string="//{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\",\"INV_ID_EXT\",\"CUST_ID_EXT\",\"MERCH_ID\", ... ,null,\"510510\",1,24]]}";

echo stripslashes(str_replace('//','',$string));
?>
```

**N.B**: This will remove `//` and `\` characters from your string but still it's not a valid json. A valid json will be like this, so in that case you've to also remove the last `]` and `...` from the string

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["TR_ID", "INV_ID_EXT", "CUST_ID_EXT", "MERCH_ID", null, "510510", 1, 24]
}
```

For that : https://eval.in/837000

For Magic Quotes issue : [PHP stripslashes problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286968/php-stripslashes-problem?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Hi stripslashes(str_replace('//','',$theString)); Gives me "{\"COLUMNS\":[\"TR_ID\",\"INV_ID_EXT\",\"CUST_ID_EXT\", ...

Comment: @zwitterion I think you are having this problem of magic quotes, see here for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286968/php-stripslashes-problem?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

try using the  [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes)  function

```
echo stripslashes($JSON2);
```

the black slashes works as an escape i belive